# Understanding the proof to selecting $p−1$ integers from a set of $p+1$ integers, so that their weighted sum is divisible by $p$ .

Tags: modular-arithmetic, proof-explanation

Could someone translate this proof to a simpler one or could you explain it to me, to more specific I am not expert in modular arithmetics?

> For every choice of $p$ elements $x_0,\ldots,x_{p-1}\in S$ you have
> $$k\sum x_i+\sum ix_i=\sum(i+k)x_i\equiv\sum ix_{i-k}\pmod{p},$$
> if you consider the indices mod $p$. So it suffices to find $p$ such elements such that their sum is not divisible by $p$, i.e. their sum is a unit mod $p$, so that there exists an integer $k$ such that
> $$k\sum x_i+\sum ix_i\equiv0\pmod{p}.$$
> If the sum of *every* choice of $p$ elements is divisible by $p$, then all elements of $S$ are pairwise congruent mod $p$, so any choice of $p-1$ elements from $S$ will do as then
> $$\sum ix_i\equiv x_1\sum i=x_1\frac{p(p+1)}{2}\equiv0\pmod{p}.$$

Comment: What is it exactly that you don't understand? Try to be a little more specific.

Comment: $$k\sum x_i+\sum ix_i\equiv0\pmod{p}.$$ and the last row

Answer (score 1):

There are enough details to be filled in to make it worth having an answer to this question.

Suppose that there are $p$ elements $x_0,\ldots,x_{p-1}\in S$ such that $\sum_ix_i$ is not divisible by $p$. Then $\sum_ix_i$ is a unit mod $p$ — presumably $p$ is a prime here — so there is an integer $m$ such that $m\sum_ix_i\equiv 1\pmod{p}$. Let $k=-m\sum_iix_i$; then

$$\sum_iix_{(i-k)\bmod{p}}=k\sum_ix_i+\sum_iix_i\equiv-\sum_iix_i+\sum_iix_i\equiv 0\pmod{p}\,.$$

If we set $y_i=x_{(i-k)\bmod{p}}$ for $i=0,\ldots,p-1$, $\langle y_0,\ldots,y_{p-1}\rangle$ is a $p$-tuple of distinct elements of $S$ such that the weighted sum $\sum_iy_i$ is divisible by $p$.

Now suppose that the sum of *every* family of $p$ elements of $S$ is divisible by $p$ and that $|S|>p$. (From the question title it appears that $|S|=p+1$.) Fix $A\subseteq S$ such that $|A|=p$. For each $x\in A$ and $y\in S\setminus A$ we have

$$x+\sum_{a\in A\setminus\{x\}}a\equiv 0\equiv y+\sum_{a\in A\setminus\{x\}}a\pmod{p}$$

and hence $x\equiv y\pmod{p}$. That is, each element of $S\setminus A$ is congruent mod $p$ to each element of $A$, and since $S\setminus A\ne\varnothing$, it follows immediately that the elements of $S$ are all congruent to one another mod $p$. It follows that if $\langle x_0,\ldots,x_{p-1}\rangle$ is any $p$-tuple of distinct elements of $S$, then

$$\sum_iix_i\equiv\sum_iix_0=x_0\sum_ii=x_0\frac{p(p-1)}2\equiv 0\pmod{p}\,,$$

provided that $p$ is odd.

The result fails precisely when $p=2$ and every member of $S$ is odd.